# How to retrieve and connect via public IP Addresses with wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm trying to build a very simple chat application with wxWidgets. At the moment, I can open the software on my local machine and on a virtual machine with it's own LAN IP Address. I'm able to retrieve each machines local IP Address via `wxGetFullHostName()` function; which I then manually enter this value into the other instance so that they connect. Everything works well at this stage.

However, now I'd like to send the .exe to a friend somewhere else. How can I get the application to expose the machines public IP address so that I can provide it to my friend to connect to my instance? Are their any other requirements to have the two instances connect to each other?

I'm using C++, but I don't think it matters much to this question.

Answer (score 0):

For a platform independent method that works behind NAT, I would suggest to use `ipify` (https://www.ipify.org/).

There are many ways of achieving this in C++ and wxWidgets. Possibly one of the best is to use `curl` (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

However, for a 'pure' wxWidgets implementation you can try the following modification to the `minimal.cpp` sample:

```
#include <wx/sstream.h>
#include <wx/protocol/http.h>
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    wxHTTP http;

    http.SetHeader("Content-type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    http.SetTimeout(10);

    http.Connect("api.ipify.org");

    wxInputStream* httpStream = http.GetInputStream("/");

    if (http.GetError() == wxPROTO_NOERR)
    {
        wxString result;
        wxStringOutputStream out_stream(&result);
        httpStream->Read(out_stream);

        wxMessageBox(result);
    }
    else
    {
        wxMessageBox("Unable to connect!");
    }

    wxDELETE(httpStream);
}
```